# Replace string characters per elements in a list Python

Tags: python, string, list

I have the following string in python:

```
'this is my string (x,x,x,x)'
```

I want to replace each x per each number in this list:

```
[1,2,3,4]
```

So, the final output should be this:

```
'this is my string (1,2,3,4)'
```

I have tried to solve it with different approaches but I can't do it.

I don't know if there is an efficient way to do this.

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Answer (score 2):

What about this one?

```
'this is my string (x,x,x,x)'.replace('x','{}').format(*[1,2,3,4])
```

Comment: `'this is my string (x,x,x,x)'.replace('x','{}').format(*[1,2,3,4])` ?

Answer (score -1):

here the solution

```
s = 'this is my string (x,x,x,x)'        

s                                        
'this is my string (x,x,x,x)'

for i in range(1, len(s.split('x'))): 
    s = s.replace('x', str(i), 1) 


s                                        
'this is my string (1,2,3,4)'
```

to prevent malcontent
you can use 
`s.count('x,') + 1` instead of `len(s.split('x'))`
if you have `x` in your string

Comment: `len(s.split('x'))` -> `s.count('x')` ??

Comment: `s.count('x,')` -- the last `x` does not have a comma afterwards.

Comment: @lenik that why i have added plus 1 to omit the last one

Comment: how come your code does not use the sample list `[1,2,3,4]` ? please, bear in mind, that the numbers are just a place holders, the actual values can be different.

Comment: @lenik yea i know but , he didn't say  that what the requirement , i only suggested this way , of course he can iterate on is own list

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212862/discussion-between-beny-gj-and-lenik).